# Mongo Authentication Failed in Nodejs Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am beginner in nodejs .
I am developing a simple chat application and 
I am trying to run the app.js file in development mode then it is fine. But when I am tring it into the production mode it does not work and give a authentication error. (as shown in the picture below) 
CODE :-

```js
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    path = require('path')
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
    session = require('express-session')
    config = require('./config/config.js'),
    ConnectMongo = require('connect-mongo')(session);
    
 app.set('views', path.join(__dirname , 'views'));
 
 app.engine('html', require('hogan-express'));   
  
  app.set('view engine', 'html');
  
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
  
  app.use(cookieParser());
  
  var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
  
  if(env === 'development'){
      // dev specific settings
     app.use(session({secret:config.sessionSecret, saveUninitialized : true, resave : true}));
       
  } else {
      //Production specific settings
      app.use(session({
         secret : config.sessionSecret,
         saveUninitialized : true,
         resave : true,
         store : new ConnectMongo({
             url : config.dbURL,
             stringify : true
         })
      })); 
  }
  
    
  
  require('./routes/routes.js')(express,app);
   
 
  app.listen (3000 , function(){
    console.log("ChatUp working on the Port 3000"); 
    console.log('Mode:'+ env);
 });
```

Picture of Window CMD :- Error Picture

[Help Me to get rid of this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OgRc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because I was using my mongolab.com username and password, instead of the database username and password.

It is working now.